# Critical issue using EF Core on UWP (unable to open database file)

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal, entity-framework-core, windows-10-mobile

**Steps to reproduce**

Follow this simple [tutorial](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/uwp/getting-started.html).

**The issue**

Start the app either in Debug or Release.

An exception occurs with **db.Database.Migrate();**.

*Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException' in Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll. 
Additional information: SQLite Error 14: 'unable to open database file'.*

This is the very first step, Migrate() method should create the database if there is not any yet (it also fails with db.Database.EnsureCreated()).

**Further technical details**

EF Core Tools version: 1.0.0-preview2-final

EF Core Sqlite version: 1.0.0

UniversalWindowsPlatform version: 5.2.2

Visual Studio version: VS 2015 Update 3

Operating system: Windows 10 10586.494

Comment: I followed the tutorial you've mentioned. It works well on my side both in Debug or Release mode. Have you tried to create a new blank project and use the same code as the tutorial? If you still has this problem, please share a [mcve] so that we can reproduce it.

Comment: @JayZuo-MSFT Did you check every tick in exception settings ? You can find a zip project here : https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6130

Comment: Oh, I just use the default exception settings, so I didn't get the error you've mentioned. Seems you've know the reason why you got this error, you can write an answer by yourself. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that, although the first-chance exception is thrown, it doesn't actually represent a bug as EF Core handles this and continues execution normally. However, it leads to a misinterpretation (the database is created anyway).

More [info](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6130)